# Why is JFrame instantiated in a different Thread

Tags: java, swing, awt

I can't understand what exactly is happening behind the scene.

If I have a main method like below, does it mean, that I have 2 threads? 
One main thread and one thread for the events like paintComponent or listeners etc? 
If so, what exactly happens in the main thread then?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        try {
            Ampelsteuerung frame = new Ampelsteuerung();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    });
    }`
```

I deleted the EventQueue and tested it without, couldn't see any difference.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the description of SwingUtilities.invokeLater() you'd understand the reasons. It's all about the synchronization between AWT events and the GUI threads

> This will happen after all pending AWT events have been processed.
>   This method should be used when an application thread needs to update
>   the GUI....If invokeLater is called from the event dispatching thread -- for example, from a JButton's ActionListener -- the doRun.run() will still be deferred until all pending events have been processed

Therefore "nothing" seems to happen if no pending event exists as in your case.